# Firebase connecting problem. "Could not find the Android Application module. Only Android Application Modules can be connected to Firebase online"

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, connection

"Could not find the Android Application module. Only Android Application Modules can be connected to Firebase online projects. Create a new Android Application Module or create/import a different Android Studio project."

I worked with Android Studio 2019 version. After upgrading to the 2021 version, the problem raises. Anyone can solve this problem?